# Visualizing results to the RCPSP

Tags: scheduling, visualization

Bot for getting better insight and reporting purposes, I am looking for a way to visualize results to the Resource-Constrained Project Scheduling Problem (RCPSP). I am aware that such results are most often represented by a resource Gantt chart. An example of such a visualization is the following from a well-known [paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4615-5533-9_7) by Kolisch and Hartmann:

[image]

This example instance comprises 6 activities and only one resource with capacity 4.

I like this kind of visualization for its simplicity. Instead of writing a visualization script myself, I was wondering if there are any tools out there that could do this for me?

Comment: It blows my mind how every 'algorithm' I've ever learned is essentially a solution to an OR Problem. Case in point: I learnt about Gantt Charts when studying methods of job scheduling by a processor in Operating Systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the IBM CPLEX IDE if you run the sched_rcpsp example you will see

[image: gantt in cplex IDE]

With python you can use docplex.cp.utils_visu as can be read in medium article [Gantt chart visualizations with python and OPL scheduling models](https://Gantt%20chart%20visualizations%20with%20python%20and%20OPL%20scheduling%20models)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please be aware that, there are two types of Gantt charts in the practical situation. First, [the task Gantt chart and the second resource Gantt chart](https://www.sinnaps.com/en/project-management-blog/resource-gantt-chart).

Besides the python library proposed by @fontanf, I think still the simplest way to depict the result of such a problem is to use some useful separate sheet templates like [this](https://templates.office.com/en-us/simple-gantt-chart-tm16400962). Also, some open-source libraries like [Nebula GANTT Chart Widget](https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/ganttchart/ganttchart.php) (in java) would be interesting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.timeline.html) ([examples](https://pythonwife.com/gantt-chart-with-plotly/))

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using Google Charts: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart

You would have to write a small pipeline that takes your result and plugs it into the JavaScript section of the Chart.

I know you said you don't want to write a script yourself, but it may be hard to find a tool that fits on top of your existing implementation (especially if you're using different packages).